# At what values of $\beta$ does $\sum a_n$ converge, where $a_n=\sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}}-1\,$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to figure out the values of $\beta$ for which $\sum a_n$ converges, where $a_n=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}}-1\,$. Here is what I have done:

I tried to re-write $a_n$ as the following, so as to get the monotonic pattern first but I couldn't even forge ahead.

$$a_{2n}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{(2n)^\beta}}-1\,$$
and
$$a_{2n-1}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^\beta}}-1\,.$$

Please, can anyone show a way-out?

Comment: Try to show (and then use) that: $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$

Comment: @ Winther: Please, how do I do that?

Comment: Computing the [Taylor series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) is one way: $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$. If you have no knowledge of that then one could also bound $a_n$ using the [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Comment: @ Winther : Okay!

Comment: Or use $$\sqrt x-1=\frac {x-1}{\sqrt x+1}\ .$$

Comment: @ dan_fulea: How do I get, $\beta$ from that such that $\sum a_n$ converges?

Comment: @Winther Hi Hans.  While Bernoulli's Inequality guarantees that $a_n\le \frac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}$, that result doesn't directly help since it does not provide a lower bound to $a_n$.  All we have is that $a_n\ge -1$.

Comment: Your formula for $a_{2n-1}$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For $\beta \leq 0$, $a_n \not\to 0$ then the serie does not converge.
For $\beta >0$. Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x} -1$. We have $f''(x) = -\frac14 (1+ x)^{-\frac32}$, hence for $|x| \leq 12$ we get
$$-C_1=-\frac14 2^{\frac32}\leq f''(-1/2)\leq f''(x) \leq f''(1) = -\frac14 2^{-\frac32} = -C_2.$$
Therefore, for $|x| \leq \frac12$, by Taylor's expansion, we have
$$-\frac{C_1}2 {x^2} \leq f(x) -\frac x2 \leq -\frac{C_2}2 {x^2}.$$
For $n$ large enough, we have $(-1)^n/n^\beta \in (-1/2,1/2)$, hence
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2 n^\beta} - \frac{C_1}{2 n^{2\beta}} \leq a_n \leq \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n^\beta} -\frac{C_2}{2 n^{2\beta}},$$
or
$$-\frac{(-1)^n}{2 n^\beta} +\frac{C_2}{2 n^{2\beta}}-a_n \leq -\frac{(-1)^n}{2 n^\beta} +\frac{C_1}{2 n^{2\beta}}.$$
Notice that $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}$ converges for $\beta >0$, hence $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum n^{-2\beta}$ converges which is equivalent to $\beta > \frac 12$. Hence $\sum a_n$ converges if $\beta > \frac12$.